# DOS batch argument substring in one line

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a batch file with the following 2 lines and change them into one line of code:

```
set arg=%1%
"C:\Program Files\TextPad 6\TextPad.exe" -u "D:\www\%arg:~14,-1%"
```

The context is that I'm using a webpage url-handler as described on
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Currently I'm doing it by setting the batch file as the url command, so the %1 is passed into that, then converted and then it runs the text-editor. But I'd rather do it all in the url command, so that I don't have to use the batch file any more.

Comment: FYI - The trailing percent in `set arg=%1%` is not needed, (though it is not doing any harm either). All that is needed is `set arg=%1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much trial & error, I found this works:

```
cmd.exe /v:on /c set arg=%1& start /D"C:\Program Files\TextPad 6" TextPad.exe "D:\www\!arg:~14,-1!"
```

Comment: +1, Great job. I should have known better that delayed expansion was required. I just didn't think it through properly. I'm deleting my faulty answer.

Comment: Be careful - I think you may have an extra space in your arg value. You probably should remove the space before the `&`

Comment: Trial and error seems to be the order of the day. I forgot to say that the param contains something like (100) at the end. So I changed your command to:
`cmd.exe /v:on /c set arg=%1&set arg="D:\Staffey\www\adev\!arg:~13!"& start /D"C:\Program Files\TextPad 6" TextPad.exe !arg!`
(a second `set arg` to do all the processing before calling the program.)  That works now - thanks @wmz and @dbenham for your help!